# Using JAXB to map elements using toString

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I am using JAXB to map classes to JSON (using genson). I would like to embed certain types as plain Strings, for instance:

```
@XmlRootElement

class Request {
    private LocalDateTime receivedAt;
}
```

Which maps to

```
{  
   "receivedAt":{  
      "dayOfMonth":21,
      "dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY",
      "dayOfYear":21,
      "hour":12,
      "minute":33,
      "month":"JANUARY",
      "monthValue":1,
      "nano":110000000,
      "second":51,
      "year":2015
   }
}
```

I would prefer to have it look like

```
{  
   "receivedAt":"2015-01-21T12:33:51+00:00"
}
```

i.e. use `toString()` on the entry value. Is that possible?

Comment: The other alternative is Genson specific and would consist in providing a custom Converter for LocalDateTime. Genson already supports some [jodatime types](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Extensions/#joda-time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create an `XmlAdapter` class that will help Jaxb convert a 
LocalDateTime to a String and back from a String to a LocalDateTime.

Something like this:

```
public class LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime arg0) throws Exception {
        return arg0.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String arg0) throws Exception {
        return new LocalDateTime(arg0);
    }
}
```

Then, either annotate your field with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` or annotate your entire package (if you want this to apply to any LocalDateTime field that is serialized), so that JaxB instantiates your XmlAdapter and whenever it finds a LocaleDateTime to marshal (or unmarshal), it will invoke the appropriate method of your XmlAdapater.

If you put on the package level:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters(
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDateTime.class, value=LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
        )
```

If you put it on your field:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime receivedAt;
```

See also this [link for more examples](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html)